# IBM Bluemix container registry error

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

We are facing an issue while accessing container registry using bx CLI container registry plugin.

Command :

```
bx cr login
```

Error :

> Logging in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'... FAILED Failed to 'docker
>   login' to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net' with error: Error response from
>   daemon: login attempt to https://registry.ng.bluemix.net/v2 failed
>   with status: 401 Unauthorized

It was working fine earlier. But now it is giving above error.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you make sure you latest versions of:

- bx
- bx cr plugin
- Docker

and try again.

It will also be worth checking that your Bluemix account is still active by running the following command: `bx iam accounts`

If the problem persists please can you raise a Bluemix support ticket and provide the output of `bx cr info` and some timestamps of when you ran the command so we can look further into your issue.

Comment: bx and bx cr plugin are the latest ones. Also my account is in active state. I dont think we will require docker to be in latest version as we are using docker inside the bluemix. Local docker has nothing to do with it. Right?

Comment: @NehaBidkar : Please see official documentation : https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Registry/index.html?pos=2 *Step 3* under *Install the IBM Bluemix Container Registry CLI*

 : Install the Docker CLI. For Windows 8, or OS X Yosemite 10.10.x or earlier, install Docker Toolbox instead.